# Mageto 2.3.4: What causes only a few category pages on the development site to redirect to the live?

Tags: magento2.3, category, redirect

We have a dev site which we use for testing any feature before it is deployed on the live server. A couple of category pages are found to redirect to the category pages on the live site. What causes only a few category pages on the development site to redirect to the live? Any suggestions or solutions that I can try out?

Comment: Hey, not sure, you can try reindex the urls and clear the cookies, I would bet on cookies I had problems with them using a sub domain for a dev

Comment: @RuiSilva in Magento 2 the url_rewrites are not handled by an indexer. This is a really weird issue, To debug I would check the `url_rewrite` table for references to the live site. Only thing I can think of right now are some of the categories were re-named but the "auto-redirect" option wasn't selected so someone added them in later with a full URL. When this DB was copied to your dev site these remained.

Comment: @Craig Yeah, for the url I usually use https://packagist.org/packages/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites to fix the url_rewrites, always worked perfectly. The cookies might be a problem too if it is a sub-domain, at least I had that problem with a dev environment.